# How to change an attribute of an element that has invalid characters in it?

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I have this HTML element:

```
<div id="n1" nameok="hello">
```

If I want to change the nameok attribute using JS, it is very simple:

```
var x = document.getElementById("n1");
x1.nameok = 'new value';
```

But let's say I have another element, like this:

```
<div id="n2" name-not-ok="hello">
```

Then, the second line is generating an error:

```
var x = document.getElementById("n2");
x2.name-not-ok = 'new value';
```

I guess the problem resides in the "-" which is very probably not allowed, so I tried something like

```
x2."name-not-ok" = 'new value';
x2("name-not-ok") = 'new value';
```

But it didn't work.
I tried to Google around, but I could not find the correct syntax in case of "forbidden" characters in the attribute name.

Sure, I can modify the corresponding CSS to avoid using attributes with the "-", then change all my HTML code... But first of all, this attribute is part of a "package" that I did not write, and secondly... There has to be a way ;)

Comment: `x2.setAttribute('name-not-ok', 'new val');`

Comment: Thanks! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) as follow

```
x2.setAttribute('name-not-ok', 'new val');
```

I'd recommend to use `data-*` attributes for custom attributes.

```
x2.dataset.nameOk = 'new val';
```

Comment: As said, I did not write those... Actually, they are the Bootstrap progressbars:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Comment: @ZioBit That means you've included jQuery. If yes, then use `$('#n2').attr('name-not-ok', 'new val');`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the new tip. I am really new to jQuery so... Any help is appreciated :) But is there any particular reason to "use" jQuery for this assignment, or is it to save 2 bytes? :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

x2["name-not-ok"] = 'new value';